# Parsing selected JSON key value pair in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a JSON Input and i need to store specific key value from it.

For eg: Lets says, i have input like below

**I/P:**

```
{
 "CLICKS": "0.14",
 "IMPRESSIONS": 0,    
 "SOCIAL": 0,    
 "REACH": 0,    
 "ACTIONS": 0  
}
```

**O/P:(In String Form)**

```
{ "CLICKS": "0.14"}
```

I am using JObject

```
var finalJsonData = JObject.Parse(jsonInStringForm);
```

I can try with JToken or SelectToken, but that will make it more complex, thats why looking for more optimized solution or inbuilt feature in C# libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
JObject input = JObject.Parse(@"{
 ""CLICKS"": ""0.14"",
 ""IMPRESSIONS"": 0,    
 ""SOCIAL"": 0,    
 ""REACH"": 0,    
 ""ACTIONS"": 0  
}");
JProperty find = input.Property("CLICKS");
JObject output = new JObject(find);
string s = output.ToString();
```

If you want to remove single property:

```
JObject input = JObject.Parse(@"{
 ""CLICKS"": ""0.14"",
 ""IMPRESSIONS"": 0,    
 ""SOCIAL"": 0,    
 ""REACH"": 0,    
 ""ACTIONS"": 0  
}");
JProperty find = input.Property("IMPRESSIONS");
find.Remove();
string s = input.ToString().Dump();
```

Comment: It seems so..lemme try your solution.

Comment: yup worked. : ) Cheers. just a question..what if i have to remove one property from input string. lets say. keep input as it is. just remove "IMPRESSIONS" field?

Comment: @KamleshArya Added sample to remove property.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your JSON code
`{
 "CLICKS": "0.14",
 "IMPRESSIONS": 0,

 "SOCIAL": 0,

 "REACH": 0,

 "ACTIONS": 0

}`
Then inside Visual Studio create an class from the pasted JSON data.
`Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes`

Comment: I am storing final o/p in string form.so there is no need for creating a new class for that.